# JavaFx Class Media

Tags: файлы, javafx, mediaplayer

Выскакивает ошибка MediaException: MEDIA_UNAVAILABLE : G:\6 - Органная хоккейная музыка.mp3 (Не удается найти указанный файл) именно с файлом https://yadi.sk/d/cd7Kmzma3Q2BWw. 
Код очень простой
File file = new File("\...\...");Media media = new Media (file); ошибка.
В дебрях интернета говорят про Code Point UTF -ничего не понял.
Прошу у вас помощи.

Answer (score 0):

С файлом все в порядке. Попробуйте следующий вариант указания пути к источнику:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.File;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Button button = new Button("Play");
        button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                File file = new File("C:/Users/UserName/Downloads/6 - Органная хоккейная музыка.mp3");
                Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toASCIIString());
                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);
                player.play();
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(button));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```